# How to debug GPB "This file cannot be processed."

Tags: google-play-books

I tried uploading several books from Project Gutenberg and I'm getting errors on a few stating in red that "This file cannot be processed".

I click on the learn more [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3097151) but it doesn't really connect me to anything debug worthy.

[image: error uploading books to GPB]
Anybody know how to get information about what exactly went awry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial things to try: Have you used an [epub validator](http://validator.idpf.org/) to confirm that it is a valid epub? Is the file encrypted in some way? (Can you view it in a browser or readium or Adobe Digital Editions)? Was the upload interrupted? I would remove and try again. In my experience though, GPB has been pretty reliable for valid epubs.

[image: example of invalid eBook result.]

Comment: Nice tool indeed! Looks like the poor [book](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/2874) is invalid.

Answer (score 3):

So I solved this issue by converting epub file to mobi format (mobi is the format kindle uses) and then converting back to epub. After doing this, google books didn't have issues processing it. There are multiple online converters you can use.

Comment: I did this for a book failing to be processed by Google Play Books and I now can read it on my phone app.

Comment: I was getting the "Processing Failed" message repeatedly.
I converted my .epub file to .mobi using Calibre and then reconverted to .epub and uploaded to PlayBooks. IT WORKED.